# Remark environment for book class: unexpected headers and amsbook error

Tags: environments, document-classes

I wrote a LaTeX custom environment for Remarks id by chapter#.remark#. My first try, using \numberwithin (followed Kopka-Daly 4th ed, p.288) is shown below with a tester.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{remarkno}
\numberwithin{remarkno}{chapter}
\newenvironment{remark}{\large 
   \refstepcounter{remarkno} 
   \noindent\textbf{Remark~\theremarkno}.
   }
{}

\chapter{ \Huge{This is the first chapter}}

\chapter{ \Huge{This is the second chapter}}

\chapter{ \Huge{This is the third chapter}}

\begin{remark}
This should be id as Remark 3.1.
\end{remark}
\vspace{10pt}
\begin{remark}
This  should be id as Remark 3.2.
\end{remark}
\end{document}
```

This works out but I get strange headers after the Chapters 1-2 pages.
Where do those come from?
If I replace `{book}` with `{amsbook}` and remove `\usepackage{amsmath}` I get
an error:  `! Undefined control sequence \@tempa -> \@nil`
Could this be due to using obsolete package versions?

Comment: Note: `\Huge` is a switch, not a command that takes an argument, so you should not put the additional `{}` pair (so `\chapter{\Huge This is the first chapter}`). But also this is not a good way to adjust the font size of chapter titles, there are packages for this like `titlesec` that let you set a style for all titles.

Answer (score 1):

Using explicit font changes in titles is bad style (for one thing, you'll get humongous titles also in the table of contents).

Besides, with the 12pt option, `\Huge` is exactly the same as `\huge`, which is used by `\chapter`, so you're doing nothing at all, except ruining the TOC.

You shouldn't define `remark` “by hand”, but using standard facilities such as `\newtheorem`. In this case, loading `amsthm` provides the desired style as `definition`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is the first chapter}

\chapter{This is the second chapter}

\chapter{This is the third chapter}

\begin{remark}
This should be id as Remark 3.1.
\end{remark}

\begin{remark}
This  should be id as Remark 3.2.
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you ***really*** want remarks to be in `\large` size (but I'd hope you don't), you can do as follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{remarkinner}{Remark}[chapter]
\newenvironment{remark}{\large\remarkinner}{\endremarkinner}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is the first chapter}

\chapter{This is the second chapter}

\chapter{This is the third chapter}

\begin{remark}
This should be id as Remark 3.1.
\end{remark}

\begin{remark}
This  should be id as Remark 3.2.
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image]